# Inserting value in a oracle table in runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values in runtime in a oracle table.
When am trying to execute the code getting below error:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 60:
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

PLSQL BLOCK:

```
declare
i integer;
begin
for i in 1..20
loop
if mod(i,2)<>0 then
insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(i, &dept_name);
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Can anyone please help me to execute this block.

Comment: where do you provide &dept_name? are manally input from some where?

Comment: yes need to give input from user

Comment: Please describe the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: ok. The logic will be like below:

--         Insert the records into the “Department” Table recursively :- 
i. Value of DeptNumber column must be an odd integer between 1 to 20. ii. Accept DeptName from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your SQL*Plus substitution variable with single quotes, or add single quotes when you enter the value. SQL*Plus substitution variables are like macros, not typed parameters.

The code below demonstrates the problem and how to resolve it by adding single quotes.

```
SQL> insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, &dept_name);
Enter value for dept_name: asdf
old   1: insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, &dept_name)
new   1: insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, asdf)
insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, asdf)
                                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here


SQL> insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, &dept_name);
Enter value for dept_name: 'asdf'
old   1: insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, &dept_name)
new   1: insert into Departments (DEPT_NUMBER, DEPT_NAME) values(1, 'asdf')

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an input department name, you want to create as many rows in the table as there are odd numbers between 1 and 20.

You don't need PL/SQL and a loop for this. You can use a recursive query to generate the numbers, then insert:

```
insert into departments(dept_number, dept_name)
with data(n) as (select 1 from dual union all select n + 2 from data where n < 19)
select n, ? from data
```